# Is there a way of making uncobyable text in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a way of making a HTML5 code that can make text that can't be copied, can someone help me?

Comment: What is *uncobyable*?

Comment: `uncobyable` ... does that mean not able to be copied? you can't. if the browser displays it, the user can copy it

Comment: give a definition of _uncobyable text_

Answer (score 2):

If you want the user to be unable to mark and co**p**y text, you can use pseudo elements:

```css
div[data-text]::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
}
```

```html
<div data-text="Uncopyable without hacking"></div>
```